# About definition of inverse polynomial

Tags: polynomials

let $p,q \in K[x]$, with $K$ a field, $q$ is inverse polynomial of $p$ if

$$(p \cdot q)= r=\mbox{unit polynomial}$$

in my studies $r=\mbox{unit polynomial}$ if $$deg(r)=0 \wedge \mbox{constant term}=1_K$$

Is it correct?

And also:

let $p \in K[x]$, with $K$ a field, then

$$\exists r \in K[x](r=\mbox{inverse polynomial of } p) \leftrightarrow deg(p)=0 \wedge p \mbox{ is not null polynomial}$$

Is it correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks right. In other words, the identity of $K[x]$ is the polynomial $1 = 1 + 0x + 0x^2 + \cdots$, and the invertible elements of $K[x]$ are exactly the polynomials of degree 0 (the zero polynomial does not have degree 0)

Comment: @Svinepels, ok.. thanks soo much! :)